# IntelliJ sbt project problems

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Every time I restart IntelliJ, I have to manually mark the src and resources folder. Is there a folder naming convention that I have to follow for IntelliJ to detect these things? Are these folders supposed to be configured in the sbt file or in IntelliJ?

Comment: Yes, folders must be configured in sbt or else intellij will drop the mark on sync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is saved in `.\.idea\modules\tracker.iml` which is configured through the `Project Structure -> Modules` dialog box. It won't save the settings if you configure it through folder tree

Answer (score 1):

From sbt [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Directories.html#Source+code)

> sbt uses the same directory structure as Maven for source files by
>   default (all paths are relative to the base directory)

```
src/
  main/
    resources/
       <files to include in main jar here>
    scala/
       <main Scala sources>
    java/
       <main Java sources>
  test/
    resources
       <files to include in test jar here>
    scala/
       <test Scala sources>
    java/
       <test Java sources>
```

If you create your project from IntelliJ select "Create directories for empty content roots automatically" and this structure will be created automatically.

[image: new project]

Comment: Thanks, but somehow, for the first build after a restart: IntelliJ unmarks those folders and I have to manually mark them again.

Comment: How do you build your project? Could you "reimport" your project after restart using "File > New > Project from Existing Sources..."?

Answer (score 0):

This is an intellij definition so it should be defined in your intellij project folder (.idea).

Comment: Shouldn't IntelliJ save my settings?

Comment: Intellij takes the setting from sbt as authoritative.